# Using "Fluid Select Output" block by condition in anylogic software

Tags: java, random, simulation, anylogic

How can we randomly select a path for fluids each time in AniLogic software? For instance, in 50% of cases, the fluid passes through path 1 and in the remaining 50%, it passes through path 2.

How can I fix the issue where only one output is always selected when using the randomTrue(0.5) function in the condition of "fluid select output" block? I have used this function to expect the desired output to be in 50% of cases on path 1 (output 1) and 50% on path 2 (output 2), but it seems that only one output is always selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `toggle()` on the `Fluid Select Output` block from upstream *before* a new batch flows through.

Test it by creating a button next to it calling `myFluidSelectOutput.toggle()` to see it in action.

Then, from an upstream block in that block's "on new batch" code, call `myFluidSelectOutput.toggle()` in 50% of the cases.

You can read on how the block works in the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/fluid-library/fluidselectoutput.html#fluidselectoutput), as usual.

Comment: I'm at a loss for words to express my gratitude. You've been incredibly helpful to me.

Comment: Please upvote useful answers, helps others with similar problems in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I cant. 15 reputation is needed :)